# Webpack - entry point common dependencies

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm using Webpack and building a library which will have multiple entry points, for example:

```
src/module1/module1.js -> dist/module1.js
src/module2/module2.js -> dist/module2.js
src/module3/module3.js -> dist/module3.js
src/module4/module4.js -> dist/module4.js
src/module5/module5.js -> dist/module5.js
```

However, each one of these modules may load one or more of the other modules as a dependency. How can I build each of these modules as an entry point without including other modules in the resulting dist files? For example, if module1 loads module2 and module3 as dependencies, I don't want the code for module2 and module3 to be included in dist/module1.js, but instead just remain as an `import` statement, taking into account the change in path (e.g. `import '../module2/module2'` becomes  `require('./module2')`).

Is this something that's possible with Webpack? [CommonsChunkPlugin](http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#commonschunkplugin) seems to almost do what I want, but that'd require any consuming project to import both a common file and each module, which I'd want to avoid.